# Avro failing to serialize BigDecimal as Decimal logicalType

Tags: java, avro

I have a list of Avro objects and I'm trying to serialize them to json and write them to disk. Here is the code I use for writing.

```
List<AvroThing> avroThings; // this is populated elsewhere
DatumWriter<AvroThing> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(AvroThing.class);
DataFileWriter<AvroThing> dataWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(writer);
dataWriter.create(AvroThing.getClassSchema(), new File("c:/avrothing.json"));
avroThings.forEach(avroThing -> {
        try {
          dataWriter.append(avroThing);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
          System.out.println("could not append avroThing");
        }
      });
dataWriter.close();
```

One of the fields in `AvroThing` is a nullable decimal type.

```
{
  "name":"amount",
  "type":[
    "null",    
    {
      "type":"bytes",
      "logicalType":"decimal",
      "precision":20,
      "scale":0
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am filling this very simply with a BigDecimal.

```
Double amount = -750.0;
AvroThing avroThing = new Avrothing();
avroThing.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
```

However, when I try to serialize this using the above writing code, I get this exception:

```
Not in union ["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":20,"scale":0}]: -750.0
org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["null",{"type":"bytes","logicalType":"decimal","precision":20,"scale":0}]: -750.0
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:740)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:205)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:123)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:87)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:156)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:118)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62)
```

I've tried using `BigDecimal.setScale(0, RoundingMode.UP)`, but this doesn't change anything other than it rounds off the last couple numbers after the decimal. The [Avro Docs](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Decimal) say that precision is `a JSON integer representing the (maximum) precision of decimals stored in this type (required).`, and since BigDecimal has no way to change precision independent of scale, I don't think that would be the solution.

I think the schema is correct, but essentially we just want to allow any value with no more than 20 digits, regardless of position of the decimal (so both `2020203984878` and `0.202378249` should be accepted). Any ideas?

Comment: This is a bug in Avro 1.8.2. See [Avro issue AVRO-1891](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1891).

Comment: Ahh... I saw that issue in my search but didn't realize it was related. Thanks for the heads up.